# Rotation with Different Layouts - iOS 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, rotation, xib

The following are the two layouts that I want have in my application.  It would be nice if when the application switches from portrait to landscape that it keeps the UILabels, BOOLs, and other objects. Because the buttons are situated differently I cannot just have the portrait view autoresize on an auto rotate. I also want to implement my own rotation lock using a BOOL and the button on the top right.

I thought about using a *-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification )notification* with a *presentModalViewController* however these didn't copy over the objects and seemed to cause [more harm then good and didn't appear to work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764850/rotation-problems-using-2-xibs-and-1-view-controller-ios).

Thanks for the help!

[image: Portrait xib]
[image: Landscape xib]

**Attempted Solutions:**

I added the landscape view to the ViewController, having both views in the view controller. I linked it up to File's Owner under the UIView *landscapeView that I added in the @interface section of the ViewController. I added [self.view addSubview:landscapeView] to the viewDidLoad method.  Then I added this piece of code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (orientationLock)
        return NO;
    else {
        if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            [landscapeView setHidden:YES];
            //[self.view setHidden:NO]; removed
        } else {
            //[self.view setHidden:YES]; removed
            [landscapeView setHidden:NO];
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

However this is not the correct solution. When I run the simulator and rotate it, the screen is not properly placed.

[image: Bad Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All things(your instance variables values) remains same when the device changes orientation. If you have only one viewController and you are showing both orieantation in the same then you can easily manage this. I suggest you to create two UIViews in the nib file that way you can do all the things you want.Hope you understand what I am talking about.Let me know if you need help.

Here is modified code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (orientationLock)
    return NO;
else {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        [landscapeView setHidden:YES];

    } else {

        [landscapeView setHidden:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}
}
```

Comment: I may need a some more help, I'm very beginner. So I should combine the two views into one xib file. How will the application know when to use which view though?

Comment: Yes When device changes it's orientation then you will get the method called shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation there you can check if interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait then you can show portrait view and hide the landscape view. Hope you will understand

Comment: also you can check your flag's value so that if flag's value is yes then only show or hide otherwise don't do anything once the flag changed

Comment: I tried what you said, but now the screen is white when not in Portrait mode.  I feel like I made a simple mistake somewhere. (see question for attempted solution)

Comment: @michaellindahl be sure you reference your landscape UIView in your nib to the IBOutlet. I often make that mistake.

Comment: try adding add subview in viewDidLoad method. Lets assume you have created portrait view by default on xib's default view and you have another view named landscape in xib. You need to add the landscape view as an subview in viewDidLoad method of the view controller. Hope this will fix the issue. If you have left out the default view and created 2 views then you should create one view as default. Beacuse when you rotate you are hiding self.view there is no need of that only hide landscape view

Comment: Removing the self.view setHidden lines allows the application to rotate with autoresizing and animation.  Adding [self.view addSubview:landscapeView]; in the viewDidLoadCode does allow the landscape view to load.  However it is not properly put on the screen (see question) and the buttons are not working.  If I apply a referencing outlet to something in the landscapeView it removes it from the portrait view.  Do I need to double my UILables, and Buttons?

Comment: send source if you can i'll correct it. In view did load you have added the landscape view but you have to also set it hidden first so that it does not display on view when device changes orientation unhide landscapeview the landscape view will then cover entire screen.

Comment: one approach is you need to manually set all the frames for both orientation. In this approach you don't need to have two views

Comment: @RahulVyas emailed the source files to your gmail.  I believe the problem is that it adds the landscape view while in portrait and when the phone rotates it applies the autorotation to the landscape view when it is already in landscape, making it much shorter and wider than it should be.

Comment: @michaellindahl I have modified the application and emailed to you.